# Accessing individual bits of variables

Tags: gcc, bit-manipulation, avr

In my application I have 2 variables (shift_counter and shift_counter_copy). What I need to do is take the lower byte of Shift_counter and manipulate the bits. I first copy the value in shift_counter in the variable shift_counter_copy. Next I interrogate the individual bits in the lower byte of shift_counter and based on the results set or clear specific bits in the lower by of the shift_counter_copy variable. I wrote the following code;

```
`void reverse_byte ()
{
    uint8_t n ;
    For (n=0; n<7; n++)
    {
        If (shift_counter(n) == 1 )
        {
            shift_counter_copy(7-n) = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            shift_counter_copy(7-n) = 0;
        }
    }
    shift_counter &= 0xFF00 ;
    shift_counter | shift_counter_copy ;
};
```

but then I wasn't sure if the compiler would accept the method shown for addressing individual bits. I thought a "struct" might work to which I crated;

```
stuct shift_counter
(
    shift_counter_0 [1];
    shift_counter_1 [1];
    shift_counter_2 [1];
    shift_counter_3 [1];
    shift_counter_4 [1];
    shift_counter_5 [1];
    shift_counter_6 [1];
    shift_counter_7 [1];
    shift_counter_8 [1];
    shift_counter_9 [1];
    shift_counter_10 [1];
    shift_counter_11 [1];
    shift_counter_12 [1];
    shift_counter_13 [1];
    shift_counter_14 [1];
    shift_counter_15 [1];
);
```

But after thinking about it I don't think it will work with my "for" loop as the compiler would be looking for the whole name of each bit. Is there any methods in C that would allow access to each bit of a variable so that a person could do a FOR loop like indicated above? Or, would the user be stuck using masks to get the value of each bit? Or, is it possible to create a definition like;

define shift_counter(1) = shift_counter_1;

and repeat that for the rest of the bits in the "struct".

Any and all help welcomed.

Comment: This question would be better if it had a succinct statement about what problem you are trying to solve.  It sounds like you have a `uint16_t` and you want to know how to reverse the bits in the lower byte while keeping the bits in the upper byte the same, right?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to put concatenation in the preprocessor directives, using `##`

```
#define shift_counter(n) shift_counter_ ## n
```

so `shift_counter(1)` will be replaced by `shift_counter_1` before the compilation. But it works ONLY on the source code at the compile time. I.e. `shift_counter(7-n)` will be replaced by `shift_counter_7-n`, you cannot use it at the runtime.

But I cannot understand why you need such a complex approach to operate bits? Just use these patterns (let's assume you have an integer variable `a`):

```
a |= (1 << n); // set n'th bit
a &= ~(1 << n); // clear n'th bit
a ^= (1 << n); // invert n'th bit
if ((a & (1 << n)) != 0) ... // check if n'th bit is set
```

For example:

```
uint16_t shift_counter_copy = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < 8; i++) {
  if ((shift_counter & (1 << i)) != 0) {  // if i'th bit in shift_counter is set
    shift_counter_copy |= (1 << (7 - i)) // set (7-i)'th bit in shift_counter_copy
  } else {
    shift_counter_copy &= ~(1 << (7 - i)) // else clear (actually not needed, since shift_counter_copy initialized to zero)
  }
}
```